# $(this).is(':checked') always returns false

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, coffeescript

I've got a collection of checkboxes and I'm trying to get the status of an individual checkbox when it is clicked. My best attempt so far has this in the coffeescript file:

```
if $('.boulderfist').length > 0
    unpressed = true
    $('.boulderfist').on "click", ->
        console.log($(this).is(':checked'))
        unpressed = false
```

And the boxes are created by this view:

```
      <%= a.collection_check_boxes(:seminar_ids, current_user.seminars, :id, :name) do |b| %>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%" class="boulderfist"><%= b.check_box %></td>
          <td><%= b.label %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
```

The console prints "False" in every instance. This includes checkboxes that started checked and boxes that started unchecked.

I've also tried

```
console.log($(this).prop('checked'))
```

and

```
console.log($(this).checked)
```

and

```
console.log(this.prop('checked'))
```

and

```
 console.log(this.checked)
```

All of those other methods return undefined or errors.

Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the event to a `<td>` not a checkbox

Try using

```
$('.boulderfist :checkbox')
```

to target checkboxes within that td class

Comment: Thank you. Now that you've pointed out the problem, it seems like a slightly better approach to move the class to the checkbox, instead of working with the CSS. Would you agree?